# retrieve list from a SQL database and create links for each lines in AS3

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm trying to do an AIR app with these conditions :

I've got a SQL database. In my table there is a "categories" column (with differents categories (computer, books..etc)).

[image]

In my AS3 I manage to retrieve "theDescription" when the user choose a categorie.
With the URLMethod and a php file.

```
    // create SQL
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM annonces where categorie = '$categorie'";
     $sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
     $num = mysql_numrows($sql_result);
    $phptheDescription = "";
    $counter = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
     $theDescription = $row["theDescription"];
    $phptheDescription = $theDescription;
    }
echo  "phptheDescription=" . $theDescription;
```

So my AS3 code is retrieving the $phptheDescription from the php and displays it in a `output_txt`.

Problem : in my `output_txt`, only ONE "theDescription" is displayed. But I have TWO items in the categorie "Informatique" (and I can have 100 items in the same categories).

How do I do to display all "theDescription" that are in the same categories ?

Ex: If I choose "Informatique", it should display "Une Surface Pro 3" and "Un IMAC". 
But it only displays the last item "Un IMAC".

And, after that, is it possible to create "links" for each item displayed ?

---

**EDIT**

Videos explaining my problems :

https://vid.me/DS2r

http://sendvid.com/6iesrygk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you already for rows, but you didn't echo the descriptions, you can edit your code to be:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
 $theDescription = $row["theDescription"];
 //$phptheDescription = $theDescription;
 echo $theDescription;
}
```

or concat all strings like this

```
$phptheDescription='';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
     $theDescription = $row["theDescription"];
     $phptheDescription = $phptheDescription.' , '.$theDescription;
    }
 echo $phptheDescription;
```

Comment: To make hyper links just wrap the $theDescription after the echo in anchor tags.

Comment: And the question for the links : http://sendvid.com/6iesrygk (it begins the same way but it's not the same video as the previous post)